# Noise isolating earphones

Tags: earphones

Which in-ear wired earphones would you recommend as the best compromise between maximum noise isolation (passive, not active noise cancellation), good bass and compatibility with android mic/volume controls for max 150 euros?

Comment: How about [one of these bad boys](https://www.bose.com/en_us/products/headphones/earphones/soundsport-in-ear-headphones-samsung-devices.html#v=soundsport_ie_headphones_ii_samsung_charcoal)? Bose is known for their superior noise cancellation and your budget leaves a pretty generous margin.

Comment: I'm sure they're a great product but maybe not so good for noise isolation.